# Difference between r'^specific expression$' and r'specific expression'

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My doubt is that I came across a regex which checks whether a password is strong or not. What is the impact of  **^** and **$** in this expression.

```
a = compile(r'^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$')
```

It has **^** and **$** signs in it. But the below code works the same as above.

```
a = compile(r'(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}')
```

If so why are they been used in the above code. Or is there reason for its usage. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would not ask the difference if you knew why caret and dollar sign are being used. Please check the marked question.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` means “beginning of a line” and the `$` means “end of a line”.
In your case, every match is a line so you don't have any problem.

Comment: Is that  good to use both variants for the password checking program right?

Comment: Using these symbols is more secure because you are sure to match a single and complete line.

Comment: By using ^ and $ we can match string with no new line characters in them ?

Comment: No you cannot, the first occurence of new line is matched by `$`.

Answer (score 0):

`^` is followed by the string or pattern by which the string will be started with and `$` follows the string or pattern by which the string will be ended with. For your case your `regex` matched with the pattern of the string without regarding the starting or ending portion.

Comment: **^ and $** ensures that there are no new line characters right?

Comment: That depends. Please read about [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) and [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE).